# Random render page content not working on AWS CloudFront (node.js)

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, https, ejs, amazon-cloudfront

My purpose is to randomly render the page content. The code I use is below:

app.js

```
routes.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var condition = Math.round(Math.random());
    if (condition == 0) {
        var data = ejs.render(index, {cquestions, questions});
        res.send(data);
    }
    else {
        var data = ejs.render(index, {cquestions, questions: questions2});
        res.send(data);
    }
});
```

I have fully test the codes on localhost and Amazon EC2 instance.
The page works perfectly on both.

However, once I query the page by the domain name (distributed by CloudFront) the page will not be randomly rendered. 
The reason I use CloudFront is to add the SSL to the page so that I can access user devices.

I guess the reason might be that CloudFront saves the rendered page in the cache so that the page will not be rendered again once I connect to the server.

But is there any way I can achieve my goal to have the page randomly rendered?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you add `res.header('Cache-Control','max-age=0');` before `res.send(...)`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I think it works !!! I also changed the TTL on CloudFront

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot oh, the page is not changing at all again......

Comment: I got it now, max-age must match TTL. Thank you very much

Comment: If the `Cache-Control` header is *really* being set to `max-age=0` then there is no need to change Maximum TTL.   Maximum TTL is the value to which larger values of either `Cache-Control` `max-age` or `s-maxage` are capped.  Smaller max-age/s-maxage values override the Maximum TTL value.

Answer (score 0):

set `res.header('Cache-Control','max-age=0')` for route, then set the max TTL on CloudFront to 0 as well.